# Mysql retrieve all nodes in a hierarchy and sum up their personal sales and group sales

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a table with all the sales person and their sales manager with the following structure:
user_id, manager_id
2,1
3,1
4,3
5,2
6,5

If I look for manager 1, I will get a list of 
2
3
4
5
6
As all of them are under manager 1

If I look for manager 2, I will get
5,
6

If I look for manager 3, I will get
4

I managed to get the list through the query below:

```
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    (SELECT user_id, manager_id FROM tbl_member
                 ORDER BY manager_id, user_id) products_sorted,
                (SELECT @pv := '" . $user_id . "') initialisation
        WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(manager_id, @pv) > 0
        AND     @pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', user_id)
```

Now I have another sales table which has the following structure:
cust_id, sales_amount, user_id

Example data:
a001, 100, 2
a002, 200, 3
a003, 150, 1
a004, 200, 5
a005, 100, 4 
a005, 80, 6 
a006, 50, 1

Am I able to use JOIN with the sql query above so that I can get the data below:
1) Sum of sales_amount of a particular user_id
2) Total group sales of a user_id (Inclusive of all nodes, exclude personal sales)

Example if I look for user_id 1, I want to get the following data 
format(user_id, personal_sales, group_sales)
2, 100, 280
3, 200, 100
4, 100, 0
5, 200, 80
6, 80, 0

Currently I am using multiple while loops to calculate the data...

```
$userSales = $this->getUserSales($rows['user_id'], $startDate, $endDate);            
$groupSales  = $this->getGroupSales($rows['user_id'], $startDate, $endDate);
```

In the getGroupSales function, I again run the below query

```
    SELECT  user_id
    FROM    (SELECT user_id, manager_id FROM tbl_member
             ORDER BY manager_id, user_id) products_sorted,
            (SELECT @pv := '" . $user_id . "') initialisation
    WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(manager_id, @pv) > 0
    AND     @pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', user_id)
```

to retrieve all nodes below the user_id, and get the sum through getUserSales() function...which the execution time is insanely slow. With about 10,000 sales records and 1,000 user id, the page load is more than 30 seconds.

Can anyone advise how do I make the query runs faster?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  If 8.0, see "recursive CTE".

Answer (score 0):

You should run an EXPLAIN On your Query and see if all Indexes are used

For your SUM i would use fowwoing query and use the INDEXES you see in the exmaple.

You can also used combined Indexes for example for user_id and the time clumn that you didn't show.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `atexdt` VARCHAR(4),
>   `amount` INTEGER,
>   `refuser_id` INTEGER
>   ,INDEX(refuser_id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`atexdt`, `amount`, `refuser_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('a001', '100', '2'),
>   ('a002', '200', '3'),
>   ('a003', '150', '1'),
>   ('a004', '200', '5'),
>   ('a005', '100', '4'),
>   ('a005', '80', '6'),
>   ('a006', '50', '1');
>
> CREATE TABLE u_m (
>   `user_id` INTEGER,
>   `manager_id` INTEGER
>   ,INDEX(user_id)
> ,INDEX(manager_id)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO u_m
>   (`user_id`, `manager_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('2', '1'),
>   ('3', '1'),
>   ('4', '3'),
>   ('5', '2'),
>   ('6', '5');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> u1.user_id,
> SUM(t1.amount)
> ,MAX(sumgroup)
> FROM 
>   table1 t1 
> INNER JOIN 
>   u_m u1 ON t1.refuser_id = u1.user_id
> INNER JOIN 
>   (SELECT SUM(t1.amount) sumgroup, `manager_id` FROM   table1 t1 
>           INNER JOIN 
>           u_m ON t1.refuser_id = u_m.user_id 
>           GROUP BY `manager_id`) u2
>   ON u1.manager_id = u2.manager_id
> WHERE u1.user_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
> GROUP BY u1.user_id
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | SUM(t1.amount) | MAX(sumgroup)
> ------: | -------------: | ------------:
>       2 |            100 |           300
>       3 |            200 |           300
>       4 |            100 |           100
>       5 |            200 |           200
>       6 |             80 |            80
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cecb038457f7aec57b1d58e05d7dcf30)*

the EXPLAIN of that query

> ```
> id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys      | key        | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra                                             
> -: | :---------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--- | :----------------- | :--------- | :------ | :------------------------ | ---: | -------: | :-------------------------------------------------
>  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | null       | ALL  | null               | null       | null    | null                      |    5 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                   
>  1 | PRIMARY     | u1         | null       | ALL  | user_id,manager_id | null       | null    | null                      |    5 |    25.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
>  1 | PRIMARY     | t1         | null       | ref  | refuser_id         | refuser_id | 5       | db_1517119808.u1.user_id  |    1 |   100.00 | null                                              
>  2 | DERIVED     | u_m        | null       | ALL  | user_id,manager_id | null       | null    | null                      |    5 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort      
>  2 | DERIVED     | t1         | null       | ref  | refuser_id         | refuser_id | 5       | db_1517119808.u_m.user_id |    1 |   100.00 | null
> ```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But the result doesn't seem to fit what I need. 
Refer to your query result table, user_id 2 should have 280 in MAX(sumgroup) as his nodes are 5 and 6

Comment: Your test is hard to read, but at the start of your question is a user manager_id, that you must check in my example, your data and what you wrote doesn add up or are contradictary, so change the example data, because u think there you find the discrepancy  and see if it fits, when not give me the new link and i will check

Comment: Let me create data in dbfiddle. Thanks a lot mate.